# D3 is not rendering in CEWP (SP2013)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, javascript

I am trying to learn D3 for use with REST endpoints (eventually).

At the moment all I am trying to do is get D3 to render anything for learning purposes.

The code below shows the d3 object loaded when I view the console so I thought all was good but nothing is showing on the page at all.   No box or bars but in the debugger I can see the new div elements added.

Code is loaded into a CEWP on a SharePoint 2013 page

HTML:

```
<script src="https://somesite/sp/tg/test/jslib/jquery351/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://somesite/sp/tg/test/sandbox/SiteAssets/jslib/d3/d3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://somesite/sp/tg/test/sandbox/SiteAssets/jslib/d3test/d3test.js"></script>

<style>

    .container{
        width: 250px;
        height: 200px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .bar{ background-color: #720570;}
</style>

<div></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    test();
});

function test()
{
    const DummyData=
    [
        {id:'d1', value:10,region:'USA'},
        {id:'d2', value:20,region:'China'},
        {id:'d3', value:30,region:'Russia'},
        {id:'d4', value:40,region:'Germany'}
    ];

     console.log(d3);
     console.log(DummyData);
    
    const container=d3.select('div')
        .classed('container',true)
        .style('border','10px solid red');

    const bars=container
    .selectAll('.bar')
    .data(DummyData)
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .classed('bar',true)
    .style('width','50px')
    .style('height','150px');
 
}
```

Comment: Are you doing something wrong with the selector for your div element? Can you please share any link from where you referenced this code?

Comment: Was following along with a YouTube video D3.JS-A Practical Introduction by Academind

Answer (score 1):

If all scripts were loaded correctly, then the issue is most likely with the selector.

The following CSS-selector will look for the very first DIV in your page:

```
d3.select('div')
```

This is definitely not what you need. To avoid selecting wrong divs, you need to add an ID to the DIV you target:

```
<div id="MyDiv"></div>
```

Then, modify the CSS-selector to target your DIV like so:

```
 const container=d3.select('div#MyDiv')
        .classed('container',true)
        .style('border','10px solid red');
```

There is one more potential problem with another CSS selector:

```
const bars=container.selectAll('.bar')
```

In the code above you are trying to select an elemnt with a bar class, but I don't see it anywhere in your code. I'm not an expert in D3, but maybe you need to create another HTML element with this class?

**[More info on d3.select()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/d3-js-d3-select-function/#:%7E:text=select()%20function%20in%20D3,matching%20element%20will%20be%20selected.)**

> The d3.select() method returns the first element in the HTML document
> based on specified css-elector.

Comment: It would append the div tag with the bar class with the code :    .append('div')
    .classed('bar',true)

Answer (score 1):

@Denis Molodtsov is right, you need to add ID to your DIV tag to make it unique.

Below is my test result in SharePoint 2013：

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>

<style>

    .container{
        width: 250px;
        height: 200px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .bar{ background-color: #720570;}
</style>

<div id="test"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    test();
});

function test()
{
    const DummyData=
    [
        {id:'d1', value:10,region:'USA'},
        {id:'d2', value:20,region:'China'},
        {id:'d3', value:30,region:'Russia'},
        {id:'d4', value:40,region:'Germany'}
    ];

     console.log(d3);
     console.log(DummyData);
    
    const container=d3.select('div#test')
        .classed('container',true)
        .style('border','10px solid red');

    const bars=container
    .selectAll('.bar')
    .data(DummyData)
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .classed('bar',true)
    .style('width','50px')
    .style('height','150px');
 
}
</script>
```

[image]